# What seems more like spam? Which do users hate more? Transactional Emails or Marketing emails?

Tags: email

I've always assumed that users would think of marketing emails as more spamy than transactional emails.

I'm getting the opposite reception though from our users.

Especially power users are very interested in things that our marketing department has to say but detests transactional emails.

Is this telling me to send more marketing and less transactional emails?

Comment: They are both spam IMHO.

Comment: Could you provide some example emails?

Answer (score 5):

If power users don't want transactional emails then offer them the opportunity to configure which transactions generate emails, in a similar way that Facebook does.

For marketing, I would give people the option to opt in or out. There may be local laws that say you have to do this anyway.

Comment: Well, for marketing emails in the U.S., you legally need to employ an opt-in list _and_ provide clear opt-out directions in each email.

Comment: Same in the UK where I am. I've updated the answer to make it more generally useful.

Comment: +1, power users will turn off the annoying notifications, and casual users will appreciate the engagement off-site when they aren't necessarily active.

Answer (score 2):

**What is the feeling of your emails?**

Are you blasting me with SALES! and FREE MONTH! ACT NOW ads?

-or-

Sending me professional emails telling me about something new and interesting you're offering?

**People love to buy things. But hate to be sold things.**

Answer (score 1):

If powerful users are more interested in marketing emails in your case, then you should give them marketing emails. However, I think you need to figure out the exact elements in your marketing emails that actually attract users and make use of them.

People never like a marketing email or a transactional email, they just like content that they think is valuable.